# MAC M Lion: Different PHP Versions:

Tags: mac-osx, installation, php5

When I run `php -v` from the terminal it gives me:

```
   PHP 5.4.12 (cli) (built: Mar 16 2013 21:46:23)
```

Then once setting up localhost etc and then i run a phpinfo page I get:

```
   PHP Version 5.3.15
```

How can I use the latest version of upgrade the current local one as I would like to install onto the server and ensure I have all the latest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first example you show that outputs this comes from the PHP command line (CLI) interface.

```
PHP 5.4.12 (cli) (built: Mar 16 2013 21:46:23)
```

The second example you show—which is coming from `phpinfo()` via your web server—comes from the PHP module that apache loads.

```
PHP Version 5.3.15
```

How did you install the version of `PHP 5.4.12` that shows up on the command line?  Also, your Apache version, is that the version installed via Mac OS X? I would run the following command to find out where the CLI version of PHP is being called from:

```
which php
```

Note that directory.  The PHP 5.4 module should be in that directory somewhere.

But wiithout knowing the details, I will recommend this if you are doing web sharing via OS X. This is based on my personal Mac OS X 10.8.3 default setup.

First, open up the Apache config file:

```
sudo nano /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

Find the commented out line that reads something like this:

```
#LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

Uncomment that line and set it to the path of your PHP 5.4 module:

```
LoadModule php5_module /my/path/to/php54/libphp5.so
```

Of course chaging `/my/path/to/php54/` to actually match your real system path to the PHP 5.4 Apache module.

After doing that, restart Apache & then check the output of `phpinfo()`.  It should match the command line output.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i will know more when I get back to the mac, but in mean time i updated the php using the command line, probably why that is set to 5.4.. Will get back later in the day but thanks

Comment: Many thanks for this it seem to work once i hunted down my libphp5 file. it was at 'LoadModule php5_module /usr/local/Cellar/php54/5.4.12/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so' and the which php showed '/usr/local/bin/php' so completely different.  Now i need to try and get mcrypt installed as its on the other version but this PHP info page shows it as NOT installed, any advise? thanks again

Comment: well i searched and found this to do brew install mcrypt php54-mcrypt and after a restart this seemed to have installed on my phpinfo at least many thanks again. Headache going...

Comment: Happy this all worked out!

Comment: not a problem, you stopped an otherwise increasing migraine :-)